# Why is my News & Weather app using so much data (and battery)?

Tags: battery-life, data-monitoring, news-and-weather

I'm running Android 6.0 on an HTC M9.

In the last 13 days, my News & Weather app has used 1.37GB of data. In that same period, Google Play Store used 1.22GB.

For a few weeks now I have had severe battery issues (from around 36 hours of light use down to 4 hours - 5 if I leave it on my desk and do nothing), and I'm now assuming that this is the cause. I don't know why a news app would use so much data, and it's all background data which makes it even more shady.

Has anybody experience their News & Weather app going out of control like this, and does anybody know how to stop it?

Comment: Have you confirmed it is actually your news app by un- installing it for a couple days and seeing if your phone goes back to normal? If it doesn't, it is probably something else. And if it isn't apparent what the cause is, I would back everything up and do a factory reset.(last resort). Try uninstalled some apps first

Comment: Unless my phone's lying to me about data usage, the app is the one using the data. I don't have enough evidence for a causal link between it and the battery. The battery issue was included as a detail in case it helped people figure out what was going on, but this question is about the data.

Comment: Ahh gotcha the post made it seem like the battery life was the issue.  I'm assuming you already cleared the cache and data from the play store and news app?  If not, give that a shot.  Other than that I am not sure as this is the first hearing about this issue, but you could always try the factory reset idea to see if that fixes it.(although this will require backing everything up which might be a pain in the ass, but will most likely be the simplest solution)

Comment: I've already factory reset the phone twice, and it has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is delete your weather app, revert the Google Play Store to the factory version, and then wait a day or so. In my personal experience, this will stop both of them from transmitting so much data, and restore your battery life to normal levels.